# Get count variable instances with variables using REST API

Tags: camunda

I have the below variables

[image]

when i count the number of variable instances with the variable conventionCode, the api returns count = 1

```
http://localhost:8282/engine-rest/variable-instance/count?processInstanceIdIn=b622ad4d-9a11-11ec-937b-0242ac11000a&variableValues=conventionCode_eq_01018
```

when i count the number of variable instances with the variable exerciceFrameworkId, the api returns count = 1

```
http://localhost:8282/engine-rest/variable-instance/count?processInstanceIdIn=b622ad4d-9a11-11ec-937b-0242ac11000a&variableValues=exerciceFrameworkId_eq_SA-FR-LAB-6969284
```

The problem is when i use the two variables conventionCode and exerciceFrameworkId, the api returns count = 0

```
http://localhost:8282/engine-rest/variable-instance/count?processInstanceIdIn=b622ad4d-9a11-11ec-937b-0242ac11000a&variableValues=conventionCode_eq_01018,exerciceFrameworkId_eq_SA-FR-LAB-6969284
```

Answer (score 0):

The API is focused on variables. So it will check each variable if your filters match.

In your example you defined 2 filters:

- `conventionCode_eq_01018`
- `exerciceFrameworkId_eq_SA-FR-LAB-6969284`

So for each variable with the name `conventionCode` and the value `01018` the first filter matches.

However, it is impossible that this matches to the 2. filter as its name is `conventionCode` and not `exerciceFrameworkId`.

So in the end you have no variables in your result.

That means it is a logical **AND** and not as you expected a logical **OR**.

See also the [REST-API Reference](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/reference/rest/variable-instance/get-query-count/)